# Does information about known input&output for SHA3-256 help to find KECCAK-256 input for the same output?

Tags: sha-3, keccak

I received two distinct outcomes from a single input using SHA3-256 and KECCAK-256:

```
input -->   sha3-256 --> output1

input --> keccak-256 --> output2
```

I want to find `input2`, which will give me `output1` after Keccak-256 hash :

```
input2 --> keccak-256 -> output1
```

Is it somewhat possible? I read somewhere that SHA3-256 and keccak-256 have only difference in padding rule. Is it possible that known input and output information for a similar algorithm (SHA3-256) can somehow help to find correct `input2` data?

Comment: It's unclear what the question designates as KECCAK-256. There is Kᴇᴄᴄᴀᴋ[256] defined in [FIPS 202](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf#page=20), and used as a building block for SHAKE128. But it has two inputs: the message, and the output length. SHA3-256 is _not_ build from Kᴇᴄᴄᴀᴋ[256], but from Kᴇᴄᴄᴀᴋ[512].

Comment: yes, I used KECCAK-256, it is used in https://keccak.team/files/Keccak-submission-3.pdf which used in Ethereum. 
I didn't know about `SHA3-256(M) = KECCAK [512] (M || 01, 256)` before your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/554/113785), KECCAK-256 (which I assume is the question's keccak-256) is a hash used by Ethereum, such that KECCAK-256(M) is Kᴇᴄᴄᴀᴋ[512](M, 256) per the terminology in [FIPS 202](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf#page=20).

SHA3-256(M) = Kᴇᴄᴄᴀᴋ[512](M ∥ `01`, 256). It follows SHA3-256(M) = KECCAK-256(M ∥ `01`). That matches the question's *"SHA3-256 and keccak-256 have only difference in padding rule"*.

Thus what the question asks is possible if we manage to make a correct guess of `input`, which we can verify by checking SHA3-256(`input`) = `output1`; and we are free to set `input2` to be `input` ∥ `01`, where `01` is a two-bit bitstring. It follows that KECCAK-256(`input2`) = `output1` as desired.

The only alternate possibilities to find an `input2` involve a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) of KECCAK-256, which is believed practically impossible.

If we want to verify KECCAK-256(`input`) = `output2` and KECCAK-256(`input2`) = `output1`, we need that the implementation of KECCAK-256 accepts both `input` and `input` ∥ `01`. That requires handling of messages of length not a multiple of 8 bits, which is not supported by all implementations.

Comment: Thank you @fgrieu! I tried to set input2 to be input||01 but don't have enough skills (for example, appending '01' to the 64 bytes message I am getting longer input string and longer output string, but I need to have 64 bytes in input2 and other stuff like this).

Am I right that if this problem is solvable though KECCAK(input2=input1||01)=output1 I could ask help on sites like upwork? I understand that offering money directly for solutions is discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ilya: If input and input2 need to be the same size, or just byte-sized (which was not stated in the original question), then the method in this answer can't be used and (as indicated in the answer) you are facing a problem that is believed impossible to solve.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification :(